# Oil your brain and learn your letters!

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

A is for Lucerne
K is for Jay-Z
M and N are for Panorama
R is for Misery and Enemy
S is for Riddler
Zed is for Radiator
Zee is for Statistics

**What is D for?**

Comment: Nice title BTW ;)

Comment: Aren't zee and zed just different pronunciations for the letter Z? I don't why they're split out here...

Comment: I don't know what D is for, but C is for Cookie and that's good enough for me.

Comment: How was this one for not being region-specific? ;-) (zed and zee)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think I have at least a partial answer. The letters are

> Greek letters, or rather the Greek letters corresponding to the given Latin ones.

Their relationship with the words is that

> their names rhyme with synonyms of the given expressions.

So:

> **Alpha** rhymes with **alfalfa** (the plant lucerne)
>     **Kappa** rhymes with **rapper** (Jay Z)
>     **Mu** and **Nu** rhyme with **view** (panorama)
>     **Rho** rhymes with **woe** and **foe** (misery and enemy)
>     **Sigma** rhymes with **enigma** (riddler)
>     **Zeta** (*ZEE-tah*) rhymes with **heater** (radiator)
>     **Zeta** (*ZAY-tah*) rhymes with **data** (statistics)

The difference between the two names of Zed and Zee reflects

> the different pronunciation of "Zeta" in Britain and in America.

A shot at a solution:

> I haven't found any relation between the letters and the prefixes to the rhymes or any overarching theme to the words. In my opinion, a letter can stand for many things, as in R above, and several letters can stand for one thing, as with M and N. (There are many letters rhyming with Zeta in the Greek alphabet.) So I pick one, maybe:
>
>  **D is for Sanctuary**.

But there may be well more to it that I have missed, so feel free to add and edit.

Comment: D could be delta. And you can have __D for Shelter__. Also, Sigma rhymes with Nygma (last name of the [Riddler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddler))

Comment: @CodeNewbie: I'm definitely superhero impaired, so I didn't know about the Riddler. Your answer makes more sense than mine: E. Nygma is the Riddler and an enigma is just a riddle.

Comment: @CodeNewbie: My idea was that sanctuary can be a synonym for shelter to follow the original pattern. It's really just a random pick from the possibilities that fit the pattern. I think I'm msissing something here, but I can't find it. (I also can't find any connection to oil or brains or olied brains.)

Comment: Aaah, okay. D for Sanctuary makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Great work, well done! D for Sanctuary is also nice, but the real challenge was to work out the underlying pattern :-) @CodeNewbie is right about Riddler though - it was meant to be Nygma and not enigma.

Comment: @randal'thor: Thanks. I've commented above that Nygma is the better answer and enigma doesn't quite fit. But I didn't know about the Riddler and his name is a wordplay on enigma, so I have no hard feelings about not getting that one.

Comment: @randal'thor: Nice and well-balanced puzzle, by the way. At first glance is seems impossible, but the zed and zee hint gave me enough to work on.

Comment: D could stand for The Beatles or Charles Manson. D = Delta which rhymes with Helter Skelter.

Comment: Btw, the puzzle's title was a reference to grease ~ Greece.